# Why can't my xterm terminal opened via a bash script find the prettytable module?

Tags: python, bash, xquartz

I have a python file which uses the prettytable. I also have a bash script that opens and runs it using xQuartz. When I open xQuartz and run the file from there, it works as expected, however when I try to run it using the script, it is unable to find my prettytable module. What might be going on?

bash script line:

```
xterm -geometry 55x24+000+000 -hold -e /bin/bash -l -c "python3 server.py 1"
```

running `python3 server.py 1` on xQuartz terminal is fine. It also works if I run `xterm` from the mac terminal and do the same.

Comment: You may be running a different `python3` depending on what's in your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @DiegoTorresMilano, you may be running a different version of python 3 depending on what's in your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`. This is possible if you have more than one version of python 3 installed.

When you are running an interactive non-login bash session, your `~/.bash_profile` will be sourced first, and then your `~/.bashrc`. Since your `~/.bashrc` will be sourced second, it can override things set in your `~/.bash_profile`.

When you run bash with the `-l` option, this tells bash to run as though it was a login shell. Then the ["Invocation" section of the bash man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#INVOCATION) tells us that `~/.bash_profile` will be sourced by a login shell, but **not** `~/.bashrc`.

What you should try is running `python3 --version` in an interactive xQuartz terminal. This will give you output something like `Python x.y.z` (for example, `Python 3.8.5`). Then you can run that specific python version by using `pythonx.y` in your bash script (for example, if the output of your `python3 --version` was `Python 3.8.5`, you should use `python3.8` in your bash script).